# how to call make command in VS

Tags: c, powershell

I am unable to call the `make` command in VS Code in the PowerShell terminal.

I wrote `make (file name)` and was expecting to compile the code but it keeps showing:

```
make hello

make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1

+ make hello
+ ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : Object NotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Did you install make for windows? https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

Comment: ...or from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2).

Comment: ...and is it in your PATH?

Comment: ... or are you actually working on the [CS50 *Hello* problem set](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/1/hello/), in which case the `make` described is not at all the typical [tag:make], but a confusingly named invention of CS50. For that, you need to follow the [instructions](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/code/) on properly setting up the course environment.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have installed make or set the correct path for make. You can refer to [this](https://www.alphr.com/the-term-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet/)